# JDBC-Mysql Amazon EC2 Connection

Tags: java, jdbc, amazon-ec2

I'm new to servers and databases. I've been trying to test out a java application that connects, reads and modifies a Mysql database that is hosted on amazon ec2.

```
System.out.println("-------- MySQL JDBC Connection Testing ------------");
    String DNS = "MYDNS";
            String myDBname = "DBNAMe"
            String MYSQLUSER = "USER";
            String MYSQLPW = "PW";
    try {

        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {

        System.out.println("Where is your MySQL JDBC Driver?");
        e.printStackTrace();
        return;

    }

    System.out.println("MySQL JDBC Driver Registered!");
    Connection connection = null;

    try {
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://" +DNS+@"/"+myDBname, MYSQLUSER, MYSQLPASS)


    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println("Connection Failed! Check output console");
        currentDir = "broke";
    }

    if (connection != null) {
        System.out.println("You made it, take control your database now!");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Failed to make connection!");
    }
```

The issue is that despite being able to connect using the credentials via Mysql workbench, adding 3306 to my security group, binding 0.0.0.0 to mysql config, I still can't get a connection going (after doing some searching of other similar problems on SO)

Anyone have any insight as to what could be wrong? I have tried many variations of the getConnection() arguments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://username@ec2-host/myDBname, MYSQLUSER, MYSQLPASS)`